# Number Of child records On Account Hierachy View Page

Tags: account

I have a button to view Account Hierarchy on Account detail page. When i click on the button it opens a pop up window and displays the account hierarchy.

At present we can display maximum 500 child records on that page.

**Now my question is that Is it possible to display more than 500 child records ? If yes then how can we implement this so it could not affect the performance also?**

I need your answers on High Priority.

I will really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to do it using pagination. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the appexchange  at this free, unmanaged package (meaning you can modify it as you wish after its installed) : https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016chCEAQ